# Gnuplot's tikz terminal produces uncompilable code

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

I would like to use the gnuplot's tikz terminal to create good looking graphs in pdf format. However, I have trouble compiling the resulting .tex file. 
My plot.gp file looks like:

```
clear
reset
set terminal tikz color standalone size 5in,3in
set output 'plot.tex'
plot  sin(x)
```

I compile the resulting `plot.tex` file with:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape plot.tex
```

Then, the compilation halts at the following output:

```
Overfull \hbox (16.34975pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 96--96
[][] 
Preview: Tightpage 0 0 0 0
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}])
*
```

At this point it leaves me the possibility to interact. Typing `\end` and then twice `<RET>` and then `x` seemingly aborts the process but the produces a working .pdf:

```
*\end
*
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \end was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par 
<*> 
? x
</home/christian/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecrm1000.600pk>
Output written on plot.pdf (1 page, 7343 bytes).
Transcript written on plot.log.
```

How could I compile the file without errors?
Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S.: I am running Linux Mint 14 and TexLive 2012 from the official repositories.

Comment: I'm not sure how this works. But try writing `set output 'plot2.tex'` after `plot  sin(x)`. In my case gnuplot doesn't *end* my files until I change the output.

Comment: You can just say `set out`, without a file name, to close the file properly.

Comment: With my version of `gnuplot` (version 4.6 patchlevel 0), the output produced by the `tikz` driver uses `lualatex`...

Comment: using `set out` as the last comment in the script did the trick, thank you very much! Newbie question: how can I mark this thread as answered?

Comment: Someone has to add an answer, and then you click the green tickmark next to the answer. @Jake, would you like to add an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the `plot` command, the output file isn't yet complete. You need to say `set out` to finish the file. This is also true for similar terminals like  the `epslatex` one.

When you use the TikZ terminal, the command `set out 'plot.tex'` creates the output file, which is empty for the time being. The first `plot` command adds the preamble, `\begin{document}`, and a `tikzpicture` containting the first plot. However, no `\end{document}` is added yet, because you might want to add more plots. Each additional `plot` command adds another `tikzpicture` that is plotted on top of the earlier ones. In order to get a complete `.tex` file, `\end{document}` has to be added at the end. This happens when you say `set output` (or `set out` for short) without a file name (or with a different file name, but that would also create a new file).